# Swift 4 Array Map nil to String

Tags: arrays, swift

so i have this simple code and have problem with swift data type, want to map this array from

```
 ["a", "b", nil, "c", "d", nil]
```

to

```
 ["a", "b", "z", "c", "d", "z"]
```

so, this is my current code

```
import Foundation

let array1 = ["a", "b", nil, "c", "d", nil]
let newArray = array1.map { (currentIndex: Any) -> String in
    if currentIndex == nil  {
        return "z"
    }
    return currentIndex as! String
}
print(newArray)
```

I am grateful if you try to solve the code. thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you declare `currentIndex` as `Any` then you cannot compare it against `nil` anymore. The correct type in your case would be `String?`:

```
let newArray = array1.map { (currentIndex: String?) -> String in
    if currentIndex == nil  {
        return "z"
    }
    return currentIndex!
}
```

However, the compiler can infer that automatically from the context:

```
let newArray = array1.map { currentIndex -> String in
    if currentIndex == nil  {
        return "z"
    }
    return currentIndex!
}
```

Better use the nil-coalescing operator `??`, and avoid force-unwrapping:

```
let newArray = array1.map { currentIndex in
    currentIndex ?? "z"
}
```

or shorter:

```
let newArray = array1.map { $0 ?? "z"  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is absolutely right but problem is that you need to pass optional argument in map statement like below and bingo your code completely work fine.

```
let array1 = ["a", "b", nil, "c", "d", nil]
let newArray = array1.map { (currentIndex: Any?) -> String in
    if currentIndex == nil  {
        return "z"
    }
    return (currentIndex as? String ?? "")
}
print(newArray)
```